# make onFling and onScroll fire separately

Tags: android

I'm trying to write a program where gestures are detected and handled. I managed to make the onFling and the onScroll event work (these events are implemented in a listener class inside and Activity). However every time I make a swipe (onFling) the code inside the onScroll() function get executed as well. For example:

```
@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
{
    //do something here, for example change background color to red
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll (MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
{
    //do something, for example vibrate
    return true;                 
}
```

In this case when I scroll the device vibrates and that's okay. But when I make a swipe and onFling gets executed the color changes to red but it also vibrates and I don't want that.

Is there any way to prevent this, so when a swipe occurs only the code in the onFling() event gets executed and onScroll() only fires when a scrolling really happens, or if not with onScroll() but to handle simple finger movement and swipe gestures separately?

Edit: I'm using the GestureDetector class.

Comment: did you manage to resolve this? I'm facing similar issue

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using `GestureDetector`.

A fling can not happen with a scroll happening before it, which is why you're receiving a `onScroll(...)` callback before the `onFling(...)`. The `onFling(...)` is called when the user lifts there finger off the screen (`ACTION_UP`) and enough velocity has been generated.

Comment: Yes, I'm using GestureDetector. So onScroll() will always get called because the ACTION_MOVE event in it, which is also happens in onFling()?

Comment: `onFling()` should only be called on `ACTION_UP`